# How do I create a PHP function to output values from different variables when called?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have different variables with arrays with different values. I need to display the values of each array item in the HTML, which I already know how to do. Problem is, I need to find the percentage of the values of each array item in relation to themselves. The equation would be something like:

blue balls percentage = blue balls / sum of all array items * 100

I'm look for a way to use a function in order to echo the results of each array item through that equation, but have no idea how to write it.

This are my arrays:

```
$balls = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);
$socks = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);
```

This is what I think my HTML should look like:

```
Blue balls make up<?php echo $percent($ball['blue']); ?>% of the balls. 
There are <?php echo $balls['blue']; ?> blue balls.
```

I'm trying to achieve this as the final result:

```
Blue balls make up 50% of the balls.
There are 7 blue balls.
```

I know the bottom echo is valid, but I have no idea how to even attempt to write the function for the top echo, or if the echo itself is possible.

Comment: `Blue balls make up<?php echo $ball['blue']*100/array_sum($ball); ?>% of the balls`

Comment: insert compulsory Friday afternoon *blue balls* joke here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$balls = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);
$socks = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);

function percent($array, $element)
{
    $total = 0;
    $elementValue = $array[$element];
    foreach($array as $entry)
    {
        $total += $entry;
    }
    return ($elementValue / $total) * 100;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    Blue balls make up<?php echo percent($balls, 'blue'); ?>% of the balls. 
    There are <?php echo $balls['blue']; ?> blue balls.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woah, this works! Just a question, could you explain what's happening in the foreach line? Specifically where the $entry variable comes from and how it acts. Thanks.

Comment: it traverses through the array ($array), assigning each element it finds to the variable $entry. it would be similar to (for $i = 0; $i < (length of array); $i++) $total += $array[$i];  it's just a cleaner way of doing it. You can use array_sum as well... this is what first came to mind

Answer (score 0):

```
function percent($getArray,$assocSearch)
{
    $total      = array_sum($getArray);
    $elementVal = $getArray[$assocSearch];
    return ($elementVal / $total) * 100;
}

$balls = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);
$socks = array(
    'red' => 5,
    'blue' => 7,
    'green' => 2
);
```

function call

```
Blue balls make up <?php echo percent($balls, 'blue'); ?>% of the balls. 
There are <?php echo $balls['blue']; ?> blue balls.
```

output

```
Blue balls make up 50% of the balls.
There are 7 blue balls.
```

Hope this would be helpful.